# Unable to verify subset of arguments passed to mocked method in specs2

Tags: scala, mocking, specs2, argument-matcher

Here's a simple specification reproducing the issue:

```
package ro.igstan.learning

import org.specs2.matcher.ThrownExpectations
import org.specs2.mock.Mockito
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.specification.Scope

class LearningSpecs2 extends Specification {

  trait Logger {
    def error(a: String, b: String)
  }

  trait mocks extends Mockito with Scope with ThrownExpectations {
    val mockedLogger = mock[Logger]
  }

  "mocking" should {
    // passes
    "be able to verify arguments passed to mocks" in new mocks {
      mockedLogger.error("message", "foo")

      got {
        one(mockedLogger).error("message", "foo")
      }
    }

    // fails
    "be able to *partially* verify arguments passed to mocks" in new mocks {
      mockedLogger.error("message", "foo")

      got {
        one(mockedLogger).error(any, ===("foo"))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
[info] mocking should
[info] + be able to verify arguments passed to mocks
[error] ! Fragment evaluation error
[error]     ThrowableException: org/hamcrest/TypeSafeMatcher (FutureTask.java:303)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2.argThat(LearningSpecs2.scala:27)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(LearningSpecs2.scala:31)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2$$anonfun$2.apply(LearningSpecs2.scala:31)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2$$anonfun$2.apply(LearningSpecs2.scala:31)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2.got(LearningSpecs2.scala:27)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2.<init>(LearningSpecs2.scala:30)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(LearningSpecs2.scala:27)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(LearningSpecs2.scala:27)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2.argThat(LearningSpecs2.scala:27)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(LearningSpecs2.scala:31)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2$$anonfun$2.apply(LearningSpecs2.scala:31)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2$$anonfun$2.apply(LearningSpecs2.scala:31)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2.got(LearningSpecs2.scala:27)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2.<init>(LearningSpecs2.scala:30)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(LearningSpecs2.scala:27)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(LearningSpecs2.scala:27)
[error] org/hamcrest/TypeSafeMatcher
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2.argThat(LearningSpecs2.scala:27)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(LearningSpecs2.scala:31)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2$$anonfun$2.apply(LearningSpecs2.scala:31)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2$$anonfun$2.apply(LearningSpecs2.scala:31)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2.got(LearningSpecs2.scala:27)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2.<init>(LearningSpecs2.scala:30)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(LearningSpecs2.scala:27)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(LearningSpecs2.scala:27)
[error] org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2.argThat(LearningSpecs2.scala:27)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(LearningSpecs2.scala:31)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2$$anonfun$2.apply(LearningSpecs2.scala:31)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2$$anonfun$2.apply(LearningSpecs2.scala:31)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2.got(LearningSpecs2.scala:27)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$2.<init>(LearningSpecs2.scala:30)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(LearningSpecs2.scala:27)
[error] ro.igstan.learning.LearningSpecs2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(LearningSpecs2.scala:27)
```

And here are the library versions as reported by the SBT dependency graph plugin:

```
[info] default:learning_2.9.1:1.0.0
[info]   +-junit:junit:4.7
[info]   +-org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.0
[info]   +-org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9.1
[info]   +-org.specs2:specs2_2.9.1:1.11
[info]     +-org.specs2:specs2-scalaz-core_2.9.1:6.0.1
[info]       +-org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9.1
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. I had to explicitly specify the Hamcrest version:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.specs2"  %% "specs2"       % "1.11" ,
  "org.mockito"  % "mockito-all"  % "1.9.0",
  "org.hamcrest" % "hamcrest-all" % "1.3", // <- this was missing
  "junit"        % "junit"        % "4.7"
)
```